# How to Mutate State of UITableViewCell using ReactorKit?

Tags: rx-swift

I am using [ReactorKit](https://github.com/ReactorKit/ReactorKit)

I have a cell `HCheckBoxTableViewCell` which has a `UILabel` for showing title and a `UIImageView` to show checked or unchecked state.

```swift
class HCheckBoxTableViewCell: TableViewCell {

  @IBOutlet weak var titleLabel: UILabel!
  @IBOutlet weak var checkImageView: UIImageView!
  
  func bind(reactor: MedicineCellReactor) {
    reactor.state.map({ $0.message })
      .bind(to: titleLabel.rx.text)
      .disposed(by: disposeBag)
    
    reactor.state.map({ $0.isSelected })
      .subscribe(onNext: { [weak self] isSelected in
        self?.checkImageView.image = isSelected == true ? Images.checked : Images.unchecked
      }).disposed(by: disposeBag)
  }
}
```

I have `MedicineCellReactor` which stores the state of the above cell.

```swift
final class MedicineCellReactor: Reactor {
  
  typealias Action = NoAction
  
  struct State {
    var id: String
    var message: String?
    var isSelected: Bool
  }

  let initialState: State

  init(id: String, title: String, isSelected: Bool) {
    self.initialState = State(id: id, message: title, isSelected: isSelected)
  }
}
```

I have `MedicalConditionSelectionReactor` which maintains the state of MedicalListViewController who populates the UITableView with the above cell.
When any row is tapped `Action.toggleCondition` is called with the respected row index. So I just want to toggle the value of `isSelected` property & then change the image of the cell to checked or unchecked based on the property value. Since the `currentState` and `initialState` of `MedicineCellReactor` are both immutable. How do I achieve this? I don't want to reload the whole tableView.

```swift
class MedicalConditionSelectionReactor: Reactor {
  
  // represent user actions
  enum Action {
    case loadConditions
    case addNewCondition
    case removeCondition
    case toggleCondition(index: Int)
    case save
  }

  // represent state changes
  enum Mutation {
    case loadedMedicalConditions([MedicalConditionSelectionSectionItem])
    case reloadList
  }

  // represents the current view state
  struct State {
    var sections: [MedicalConditionSelectionSection] = [MedicalConditionSelectionSection(items: [])]
  }

  let initialState: State = State()
  
  func mutate(action: Action) -> Observable<Mutation> {
    switch action {
    case .loadConditions:
      let medicalConditions = OptionsModelDBProvider<RealmMedicalConditionModel>().fetch()
      let conditions = medicalConditions.toArray().map { item -> MedicalConditionSelectionSectionItem in
        // let isSelected = arrayOfMedicalConditionID.contains("\(item.ID)")
        let medicalCell = MedicineCellReactor(id: "\(item.ID)", title: item.name, isSelected: false)
        return MedicalConditionSelectionSectionItem.medicalCondition(medicalCell)
      }
      return Observable.of(Mutation.loadedMedicalConditions(conditions))
      
    case let .toggleCondition(indexOfCell):
      let state = currentState.sections[0].items[indexOfCell]
      switch state {
      case let .medicalCondition(reactor):
        // TODO:- How to toggle the isSelected bool property of MedicineCellReactor.State. Since this is immutable.
        // reactor.currentState.isSelected = false
        break
      default: break
      }
      return Observable.of(Mutation.reloadList)
      
      
    default:
      return Observable.of(Mutation.reloadList)
    }
  }
  
  func reduce(state: State, mutation: Mutation) -> State {
    var state = state
    switch mutation {
    case let .loadedMedicalConditions(conditions):
      state.sections[0].items = conditions
    default:
      break
    }
    return state
  }

}
```

Comment: What is the type of `medicalConditions`?

Comment: Why do you even _have_ a `MedicineCellReactor`? Your cell doesn't conform to ReactorKit.View and the state can't change anyway. I suggest you don't use a reactor in this situation.

Comment: @DanielT.  `medicalConditions` is of type Realm `Object`

Comment: Okay @DanielT. I have removed ReactoreKit from the `HCheckBoxTableViewCell`

Comment: @DanielT. can you see this https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/245996/how-to-bind-viewmodel-to-viewcontroller-using-rxswift